# Question marked as duplicate but no link to original question. What to do?

Tags: discussion

This question has been marked as a duplicate but there is no link to original quetion:

- [Setting proxy from terminal](https://askubuntu.com/questions/158557/setting-proxy-from-terminal)

Why is this so? And what can be done for such questions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The link was probably mistakingly removed after an edit to the question. You can find the duplicate in the question's [revisions](https://askubuntu.com/posts/158557/revisions).

I've re-added the duplicate manually to the question for future vsitors.

Answer (score 0):

You still have the `Linked` on the right-hand panel. This specific question is probably duplicate of ['apt-get' does not work with Proxy](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23666/apt-get-does-not-work-with-proxy?lq=1).